# fancybox 3 and navigation bootstrap issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, fancybox-3

```
fancybox 3 and navigation bootstrap issue
When fancybox 3 is open the navigation bootstrap moves to right like the scrollbar is hidden. please see the picture below
```

please see the picture below
please see the picture below
please see the picture below

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNsEG.png


below is may fancybox 3 simple code.

<a href="img/portfolio/web/1001.png" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
  <img src="img/portfolio/web/1001.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
</a>

below is may navigation bootstrap in navbar-fixed-top.
```

```
<div class="container">
/// codes etch......
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See #1 from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq

Basically, just add `compensate-for-scrollbar` class to your navigation element.